# How to initialize an Array of Nested structures

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I'm trying to write a program that sets up a nested structure and then initializes an array of that structure.  It's giving me some weird errors.  Here's all the relevant code:

```
//Structure called Stats for storing initial character stats
struct Stats{
    string name;
    int level;
    int HP;
    int STR;
    int CON;
    int DEX;
    int INT;
    int WIS;
    int CHA;};

//Structure called Growth for storing character growth per level.
struct Growth{
    int HPperlvl;
    int STRperlvl;
    int CONperlvl;
    int DEXperlvl;
    int INTperlvl;
    int WISperlvl;
    int CHAperlvl;};

struct Holdstats{
    Stats classstats;
    Growth classgrowth;};

const int SIZE = 10;

Holdstats classlist[SIZE];

Holdstats charlist[SIZE];

//Define initial classes, to be stored in the Classes structure
classlist[0].classstats = {"Fighter", 1, 18, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
classlist[0].classgrowth = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

classlist[1].classstats = {"Wizard", 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
classlist[1].classgrowth = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

My compiler thinks that when I type "classlist[0].classstats" that I'm trying to initialize an array of size 0.  The way I read this I'm trying to access the first element of the classlist array.  Is this written correctly?

It'd be great if someone could give me a short example of what such an array looks like.  From there I'm thinking of writing it as a vector

Comment: Didn't even read the question yet, but you need a semicolon after the struct declaration.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, bad copy paste error lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show what all your types are but you should be able to take this basic approach.

```
Holdstats classlist[SIZE] = {
    { {"Fighter", 1, 18, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1} },
    { {"Wizard", 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1} },
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea you could do it like that.  This solves my problem but I'm still interested in why I was getting the error in the first place

Answer (score 0):

your struct `Holdstats` holds two other structs of type `classstats` and `classgrowth`. Remember these are structs, not arrays, so im not completely sure why you assign them like so:

```
classlist[0].classstats = {"Fighter", 1, 18, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
```

i would guess you want to fill out the stats struct inside the holdstats struct itself, which would be done below:

```
classlist[0].classstats.health = 15; //guessing you have a member named health
//OR if you create a constructor for you classstats with the proper copy constructor
classlist[0].classstats = classstats("Fighter", 1, 18, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
//OR if you have an assign function
classlist[0].classstats.assign("Fighter", 1, 18, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: It's still acting like when I type classlist[0].classstats that I'm trying to initialize an array of size 0 instead of accessing the first element of the array.  Any idea how to fix this?  Thanks very much though, I think I get why I have to do it that way